# Compile with option

Tags: xetex, options

On an exact example. Here is the CV template: https://github.com/afriggeri/cv. It says that:

> there is an `print` option which renders in black and white

And in `.cls` file there is indeed `\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}`

Now can anybody explain me how to compile with `print` option? Because everything that I've managed to find with google was some passing of options into packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the option to the documentclass:

```
\documentclass[print]{friggeri-cv}
```

Comment: thank you. Can't be done somehow in the other way? Or can you suggest how can it be automated?

Comment: @Uko I am afraid this is the easiest option :)